# What is the time complexity of the code?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Is the time complexity of the following code O(NV^2)?

```
for i from 1 to N:
    for j from 1 to V:
        for k from 1 to A[i]://max(A) = V
           z = z + k
```

Comment: It is just like you said. The only exception could be if A[i], even though can maximally be V, it will, for example, be always constant "on average" (amortized complexity). 
Not going into more detail - there are lots of good resources for that. And universities, of course.

Comment: For an example of what Pawell is saying, suppose that A is full of zeroes except for a single value, which is V. The inner loop will only run for that i so the total time complexity will be O(NV + V^2)

Comment: Yes, the time complexity is O(NV^2). That is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah,whenever we talk about `O-notation`, we always think about the ***upper-bound(OR the worst case)***.

So,the complexity for this code will be equal to

```
O(N*V*maximum_value_of_A)
=O(N*V*V)   // since,maximum value of A=V,so third loop can maximally iterate from 1 to V---V times
=O(N*V^2).
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure it is **O(NV^2) as it means the code is never *slower* than that.** Because max(A) = V, you can say the worst case would be when at every index of A there is V. If so, then the complexity can be limited to O(NV*V).

You can calculate very roughly that the complexity of the `for k` loop can be O(avg(A)). This allows us to say that the whole function is Omega(NV*avg(A)), where avg(A) <= V.

Theta notation (meaning asympthotical complexity) would can be stated like **Theta(NV*O(V))**, O(V) representing complexity of a function which will never grow faster than V, but is not constant.